# Is there a difference between compiling projects in Visual Studio 2008 Pro and the Standard version?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc

We are using two different versions of Visual Studio 2008, the Pro and Standard one. I started a Visual C++ MFC project using the Pro version. My teammate wanted to use my project with the standard version, but all he gets are a lot of compile errors about missing afxheaders and stuff like that.

We are really helpless and don't know where to search first. Hoping one of you guys can help us out. Sorry for my bad English, hope you all understand the problem.

Regards,
buk

Comment: Your English wasn't bad at all.

Comment: Maybe just didn't install the mfc stuff when installing vc. Normally the afx header belong to mfc which should be there.

Comment: the mfc stuff is installed on both versions. because we only work with the microsoft foundation classes

Comment: Can you post (some of) the errors you are getting?

Comment: @Totonga, Standard Version has no possibility to select or not to select MFC during installation. Standard version has simplified installer with no checkboxes in it.

Answer (score 2):

Check that `Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->VC++ Directories` contains `$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include` in `Include files` section. And check that afxheaders are in that include folder.

Is there SP1 for Visual Studio installed on both computers? May be MFC Feature Pack is required to compile your project...

Answer (score 2):

MFC and ATL are optional components at VS installation. Have your partner run a "change installed components" install and make sure the MFC and ATL components are installed. They should end up in %programfiles%\Visual Studio 9.0\VC...

Comment: hi,

yes my teammate has installed the whole mfc and atl components. since yesterday he has a lot of other problems with vs2008 standard. he is running vs2003 and vs2008 coeval. maybee this is the problem...

thx for all your answers!

regards,
buk

Comment: we need some more specific error messages to troubleshoot better

Answer (score 1):

By Standard version you don't mean the Express Edition, right? That one comes without MFC which would explain your problem.

Comment: yes right! i mean the standard edition http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/vstudio/bb894689.aspx